# Размер дата-сета для классификации картинок

Tags: машинное-обучение, dataset

Хочу сделать классификатор для распознавания персонажа из мультика, скажите, пожалуйста, сколько картинок необходимо подготовить для дата-сета? Вот сам персонаж:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главное правило работы с нейросетями -  "примеров много не бывает". Другими словами -  чем больше, тем лучше.